# Can I use Rolling and Window cross-validation techniques to check feature importance and forecasting error stability?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, cross-validation, causality

I want to propose a simple experiment. Let's say I have a time series data, where I first split data into train and test sets and then work with my training set to pick the best model to do forecast analysis.

Usually we use cross-validation techniques to tune hyperparameters of a Machine Learning model, however, when dealing with complex time series structures, we can have a significant change in performance for a specific period of time and I would like to assess the stability that my model produces as it performance's varies over a specific window.

To clarify, let's say I use Rolling cross-validation, for h = 1, where:
$ \hat{y}_{t+h} $ is my model's prediction and my metric is RMSE, so for 10 iterations, I would get 10 different RMSE for each timestamp: $ t_{1}, t_{2}, .., t_{10} $. And I generate a graph, like this:

[image]

The plot is not so important, it just servers to illustrate my question.

Now, my question is: Can I rely in a model where my RMSE curve is so unstable? Or should I trust on my initial train/test validation results and get only hyperparameters for this method?

Also, regarding feature importance, in [Machine Learning: An Applied Econometric Approach](https://pubs.aeaweb.org/doi/pdfplus/10.1257/jep.31.2.87) the authors discuss how the coefficients choosed by a LASSO Regression model can vary a lot depending on CV split. Here I am trying to use this concept for time series as well, can I infer that features which are more stable through my whole cross-validation are in fact the best predictors for my target variable?

To summarize, when using big windows for cross-validation techniques, should I expect stability in a good performance model, or I only hope to get good results in a shot time window?

Answer (score 0):

> To summarize, when using big windows for cross-validation techniques, should I expect stability in a good performance model, or I only hope to get good results in a shot time window?

The answer here is: It depends on what your data is.

If there's a lot of hidden variable affecting your target, then you shouldn't.

If the dataset is fully deterministic (e.g. the [1,2,3,4,5... etc] -> [1,4,9,16,25... etc]) you should, assuming you picked a good model.

If you are trying to estimate how "accurate" the model is then maybe a good approach would be to take a worst-case scenario (i.e. take the highest RMSE) and test on as many different folds as possible and assume that in-practice you won't get much worst than the worst case scenario... but again, this assumption depends on how deterministic the data is.

If you are just overfitting on noise this doesn't really hold.